# Summing values from across worksheets

Tags: microsoft-excel

Let's say I have two worksheets as below:

```
WorksheetA
==========
    A      B
1   John   5
2   Dick   4
3   John   4

WorksheetB
==========
    A      B
1   Adam   9
2   Dick   2
3   John   8
```

What I want to do is create a third worksheet that calculates the total for each person summed from the first two sheets:

```
    A      B
1   Adam   9
2   Dick   6
3   John   17
```

What formula do I put into column B in this third worksheet to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((WorksheetA!A1:A20=A1)*(WorksheetA!B1:B20))+SUMPRODUCT((WorksheetB!A1:A20=A1)*(WorksheetB!B1:B20))
```

and copy down:

[image]

Extend the formula past ***20*** if you require.